# Only allow whitespace after comma and restrict special characters in text field using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to restrict a user from being able to enter whitespace or hit the spacebar after characters (unless they enter a comma) as well as restrict all special characters except numbers and letters.

The desired output would be something like: "ab, c" or "abc, def, g, h..."
The user would only be allowed to have whitespace or hit the spacebar after a comma. A comma is the only special character permitted.

What I have so far but it's only allowing for 1 comma:

```
function checkKey() {
    var clean = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, "")
                           .replace(/(,.*?),(.*,)?/, "$1");
    // don't move cursor to end if no change
    if (clean !== this.value) this.value = clean;
}

// demo
document.querySelector('input').oninput = checkKey;
```

Comment: Maybe remove space after a non-comma or start of string? `.replace(/(^|[^,])\s/, "$1");`?

Comment: Forgot `g`, you need `.replace(/(^|[^,])\s+/g, "$1");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all whitespaces after a non-comma char, you can use this solution with no lookbehind:

```js
.replace(/(^|[^,])\s+/g, "$1")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWiot8/1). *Details*:

- `(^|[^,])` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` refers to this group value): start of string (`^`) or (`|`) any non-comma char (`[^,]`)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces.

In your code:

```js
function checkKey() {
    var clean = this.value.replace(/[^\d,]/g, "").replace(/(^|[^,])\s+/g, "$1");
    if (clean !== this.value) {
        this.value = clean;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user992731 This solution should be preferred whenever you need to support any JS environments, since some of them, like Safari at the moment of writing, do not support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, "")` , you are removing all chars except digits and a comma, not allowing chars a-z anymore.

You can first remove all characters except `[^a-zA-Z0-9, ]+`, and then in browsers that [support a lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can allow a space when it is not directly  preceded by a comma.

```js
function checkKey() {
  const clean = this.value
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9, ]+/g, "")
    .replace(/(?<!,) /g, "");
  if (clean !== this.value) this.value = clean;
}

document.querySelector('input').oninput = checkKey;
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```